# Exercise 1.1.9 from West

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

Currently I am reading the first edition "Introduction to Graph Theory" by Douglas B. West.

Exercise 1.1.9 states the following:

**1.1.9.** Suppose that $G$ is a simple graph having no vertex of degree $0$ and no induced subgraph with three edges. Prove that $G$ has at most four vertices.

**Counter-example:** Let $V(G) = ${$ 1,2,3,4,5 $}$ $ and $E(G) = ${$ 12,23,45 $}$ $.

**Is this counter-example correct ?**

**EDIT:**

Came up with this approach but I'm stuck.

**Proof.** Because the degree of every vertex in $G$ has degree of at least 1 then

$$
\sum_{v \in V}^{} \text{deg}(v) \geq |V| 
$$

and recall that half the sum of all degrees in $G$ is the size of the edge set, thus

$$
|E|\geq \frac{1}{2} |V|
$$

Now, if $G$ does not contain any induced subgraph $H$ with three edges, that implies there is no 4-vertex or 5-vertex subset of $V(G)$ for which the induced subgraph under that subset contains three edges. Because $|E| \geq 3$ for $|V| \geq 5$ then $G$ must contain a three edge subgraph (and im stuck here)

Comment: $G$ is an induced subgraph of $G$, and has three edges.

Comment: The induced subgraph doesn’t need to be proper

Comment: Oh, so this was an error of definition on my part. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelBurr What does proper mean?

Comment: A proper subset is a subset that isn’t equal.  This is just a way of saying that the induced subgraph could be all of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Counter-Example almost contains the Proof !**

When we have graph $G$ with $5$ or more vertices , then a sub-graph ( which might be $G$ itself ) will contain $5$ vertices , which will look like your Example.
Let all the vertices be $0$ Degree , unconnected to other vertices.
We want the Case where there are no $0$ Degree vertices , while we have $5$ such $0$ Degree vertices. Hence we can connect ( arbitrarily ) vertices $1$ & $2$ to get $(1,2)$.

We still have $3$ vertices with $0$ Degree , with $1$ Edge.

Adding a new Edge either will reduce that count by $1$ ( eg $(1,3)$ ) or will reduce that count by $2$ ( eg $(3,4)$ ) , leaving us with atleast $1$ vertex with $0$ Degree.

Adding a third Edge will give a subgraph with 3 Edges , while not adding a third Edge will give a graph with at least $1$ unwanted $0$ Degree vertex.
**Either way , the Conclusion holds !**

At the Point where we have 3 Edges , adding more Edges **might eliminate** all the $0$ Degree vertices , though it **can not eliminate** the currently **existing** subgraph having $3$ Edges.

**Maximal Example :** $E(G)=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with $V(G)=\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$

Comment: But what if you then add a fourth edge? This argument is unfinished.

Comment: Nice Catch ! I have added the last 2 Sections , @MishaLavrov , to make it complete now.

Comment: It's not obvious that we can't eliminate every existing $3$-edge subgraph after one appears. Consider that we can pull it off with $4$ vertices: if we have edges $\{(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (1,4)\}$, that's also a maximal example.

Comment: Oh , you are right , @MishaLavrov , I will have to rethink that now !

Comment: Hint: first prove that the graph must have maximum degree 2 or less, then prove that it can have at most two connected components. Then analyzing the remaining possibilities becomes much easier.

Comment: "must have maximum degree 2 or less" as in the degree of any vertex in G is 2 or less? @MishaLavrov

Comment: @BryanBusby Yes, exactly. One of two things goes wrong if you have a vertex with $3$ neighbors...

Comment: I see that these two components are P_1 and P_2. Adding an edge strictly induces a 3-cycle or a 3 edge path. I just don't know how to prove that adding an arbitrary number of edges under an n vertex graph preserves the property in 1.1.9. @MishaLavrov

Comment: @BryanBusby You shouldn't try to reason through what happens if you add edges. Just reason about what the graph $G$ can and cannot have. (You're missing one component, though: $C_4$. And if you're following West, you should call the possible path components $P_2$ and $P_3$, by the number of vertices they have.)